# Why are some of my html tags following css and others not?

Tags: python, html, css, django

So I have a normal html file with tags like  and  etc.

I have this css file:

```
html, body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    backgound-color:blue; 
}

a {
    /* Note: For whatever reason this does not apply to templates/tags/naviagtion.html */
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

For whatever reason when this is applied to my html file via:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/base.css" />
```

Note: the  is placed in base.html which it the base template.  The background of the body and the text-decoration of the link does not change to the css style.  Other tags like div change their width, float, etc to the style of the base.css file.  When I go and personally edit the tag via style="" in the tag, the attributes are applied.  Why do the styles get applied with style="" and not from the css file.  I have no inline css in the base.html file that overrides anything.  Also, the attributes such as margin and padding for html, body from the css file get applied while the background-color doesn't.  What is going on?

Thanks!

The base.html file pretty much looks like this

```
....
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/base.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- 
    <div class="left_holder" >
    </div>
    -->
    <div class="center_holder" >
        <div id="top_1" >
            <div id="search" class="top_left" >
                <!-- [ searchbar ] -->
                {% include "tags/search.html" %}
            </div>
....
```

the navigation.html file:

```
<div><a href="/" >Home</a></div>
```

Sorry there won't be a url since this is on localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling error fixed. Also css is case sensitive.

```
html, body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    background-color:blue; 
}

a{
    /* Note: For whatever reason this does not apply to templates/tags/naviagtion.html */
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You said text-decoration:none is not getting applied.
Did you mean that you see an underline below the link or you see an outline after clicking?

You should not see an underline if you have text-decoration:none; in your css.

If you see a border or ouline, try adding outline:none; as well to the css for a{}

Comment: LOL WOW can't believe it was a spelling error... Feel like I've just wasted you'll time... Sorry about that, I read over my work more often now...

Comment: @Derek A "smart" editor will indicate blatantly invalid CSS, such as above. Alternatively, use a [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using an HTTP debugger to make sure your .css file is being loaded. I suspect it isn't. For Windows use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). If the .css isn't being loaded you'll see a red 404 in the list.

Also try using your browser's debugging tools to ensure the .css file is loaded.
In Chrome or Safari for instance, just right click on the page and select 'Inspect element'. Click on the 'Resources' tab at the top and make sure your .css file is listed in the left panel. If not your path to the file is probably incorrect.

Comment: when i go to page source I get <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/base.css" /> and i can click on the resource link which takes me to the correct base.css file with all my styles

Comment: In addition you can right click on one of the <a> tags that isn't working and inspect the list of styles in the right panel. It will show you where the derived style is coming from. You may see your .css file listed and being overridden by something else, but if you don't see it at all it means it's not being loaded or applied for some other reason

Answer (score 0):

Is `templates/tags/naviagtion.html` being included in base.html or is it a separate file?

It is really critical that you include sample HTML code as well since that is also part of the problem. Or if you have a URL where we can see the problem that would help too.

Comment: navigation.html is include in the base.html, posted samples above now, sorry this is on localhost, no url, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `background-color`, but try for the link:

```
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

The selector `a` is usually too general for overriding link style set by the browser with an `a:link` selector.